# Present function results to UILabel (Swift) (SwiftyStoreKit)

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, ios10

I am wanting to display the price of the SKProduct item inside my label, rather than it being an alertView, as presented by SwiftyStoreKit.

In the viewDidLoad, I tried

```
coralsAppLabel.text = getInfo(PurchaseCorals)
```

but this results in the error that I cannot covert a type () to a UILabel.

This is based on the SwiftyStoreKit code below.

```
enum RegisteredPurchase : String {

case reefLifeCorals         = "ReefLife4Corals"
}


@IBOutlet weak var coralsAppLabel: UILabel!


func getInfo(_ purchase: RegisteredPurchase) {

    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([purchase.rawValue]) { result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        self.showAlert(self.alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result))
    }
}

func alertForProductRetrievalInfo(_ result: RetrieveResults) -> UIAlertController {

    if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
        let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
        return alertWithTitle(product.localizedTitle, message: "\(product.localizedDescription) - \(priceString)")
    }
    else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {
        return alertWithTitle("Could not retrieve product info", message: "Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
    }
    else {
        let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error. Please contact support"
        return alertWithTitle("Could not retrieve product info", message: errorString)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're trying to assign `Void` (aka `()`) value that your function `getInfo` implicitly returns to a `String?` property of `UILabel`. That's not going to work.

You can't easily return needed info from `getInfo` function either because it does asynchronous call. One way to accomplish what you need is to re-factor the code a bit to something like following (didn't check for syntax errors, so be wary):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getProductInfoFor(PurchaseCorals, completion: { [weak self] (product, errorMessage) in
        guard let product = product else {
            self?.coralsAppLabel.text = errorMessage
            return
        }

        let priceString = product.localizedPrice!
        self?.coralsAppLabel.text = "\(product.localizedDescription) - \(priceString)"
    })
}

func getProductInfoFor(_ purchase: RegisteredPurchase, completion: (product: SKProduct?, errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([purchase.rawValue]) { result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        let extractedProduct = self.extractProductFromResults(result)
        completion(product: extractedProduct.product, errorMessage: extractedProduct.errorMessage)
    }
}

func extractProductFromResults(_ result: RetrieveResults) -> (product: SKProduct?, errorMessage: String?) {
    if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
        return (product: product, errorMessage: nil)
    }
    else if let invalidProductId = result.invalidProductIDs.first {

        return (product: nil, errorMessage: "Invalid product identifier: \(invalidProductId)")
    }
    else {
        let errorString = result.error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error. Please contact support"
        return (product: nil, errorMessage: errorString)
    }
}
```

Here you have your `SKProduct` or `errorMessage` in `viewDidLoad` in the completion closure and you are free to do whatever you want with it: show alert, update label, etc. And overall this code should be a little bit more flexible and decoupled which is usually a good thing ;)

Comment: I made a couple of changes to your code to reflect what Swift 3 required.  Plus, I changed data retrieved as I only needed price.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you.